# How can I set a new array without an object that is selected with react.js, splice?

Tags: reactjs, splice, array-splice

How can I set a new array without an object that is selected?

```
  const [chips, setChips] = useState([
    { type: "keyword", text: "000" },
    { type: "keyword", text: "111" },
    { type: "keyword", text: "222" }
  ])

  const handleDelete = idx => {
    const newChips = chips.splice(idx, 1);
    setChips(newChips);
  };

   const renderChips = useMemo(
    () =>
      chips.map(({text}, idx) => (
        <Chip
          key={text}
          onDelete={() => handleDelete(idx)}
        />
      )),
    [chips, handleDelete],
  );
```

Let's say I clicked `chips[1]`, I'd like to remove `chips[1]` from the chips array and set a new array without `chips[1]`.

So the new array will look like this.

```
([
    { type: "keyword", text: "000" },
    { type: "keyword", text: "222" }
  ]
```

How can I do it?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is important to deep copy the `chips` array correctly in this case, otherwise the objects inside chips array will be copied by reference. So in `handleDelete` function, you can try:

```js
const handleDelete = (idx) => {
  const newChips = chips.map((chip) => ({...chip})); // deep copy
  newChips.splice(idx, 1);
  setChips(newChips);
};
```

**UPDATE:** Also tried the following, which works too, so a superficial copy will work too, and a full nested copy isn't actually needed:

```js
const handleDelete = (idx) => {
  const newChips = [...chips]; // superficial copy
  newChips.splice(idx, 1);
  setChips(newChips);
};
```

Sandbox: https://codesandbox.io/s/ecstatic-haslett-pyh4im?file=/src/App.js:0-661

Answer (score 0):

You using splice wrongfully here, I'll invite you to check here the doc : https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice
This modify the original array and doesn't return anything, which means in your case `newChips = []`

Instead you could do

```
const newChips = chips;
newChips.splice(idx, 1);
setChips(newChips);
```

On the first line, when assigning chips, you could do a hard copy here, but I think you can get away without

Answer (score 0):

[`Array#splice()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/splice) does not return a modified array but instead modifies the current one. What you need to do is adapt your `handleDelete` function as follows:

```
const handleDelete = idx => {
  setChips([...chips].splice(idx, 1));
};
```

Comment: I wonder what `newChips` will look like. You meant `chips`? if so, when I click `chips[1]` , I see `chips[1]` rendered so `chips[0]` and `chips[2]` are removed.